# ESLint Errors do not show up in Intellij Editor Window

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, eslint

I use IntelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE 2016.3.5 for my web project. I did set up the native ESLint feature and when I run "Inspect Code" for a specific JavaScript file everything works like a charm.

[image]
[image]

But as you can see, there is no highlighting in the editor view although I double checked that I activated it in the setting.

[image]
[image]

All other code inspection highlightings work like expected. Is there any super obvious thing I am missing?

Comment: What severity is configured for `no-console` rule in .eslintrc? Also, try switching editor color scheme to default (Darcula, etc.) - does the problem persist?

Comment: `no-console` is set to 0 and I already tried different color schemes with the same result.
But today I installed IDEA 2017 and everything works fine. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: this is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25605 then; it's fixed in 2017.1

Answer (score 0):

Installing the new IntelliJ Version (IntelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE 2017.1) solved the problem.